# Render one component from another without it being a child component

Tags: reactjs, components

You can see that 2 components Home and Init are defined in the App component and also a Menu.
Inside Init there is a condition in which it calls the Home component, through a Redirect. The Home component is rendered but the Menu component is not. How is it possible to render the Menu component from the Init component?

const App: React.FC = () => {

```
return(
<IonApp>
<IonReactRouter>
<IonSplitPane contentId="main" when="(min-width: 4096px)">
      <Menu />
  <IonRouterOutlet id="main">

    <Route path="/" render={() => isReg ?   <Home />:<Init /> } />
    <Route path="/home" component={Home}></Route>
    <Route path="/init" component={Init} />

  </IonRouterOutlet>
  </IonSplitPane>
</IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>

);
};

export default App;
```

Inside Init there is a condition where Home is call

```
if(ready){
    return(<Redirect push={true} to="/home" />);
}
```

But  is not render. How can I make a render for Menu?

Comment: is your ready meant to mean the page is loaded?

Comment: ready is a boolean hook in Init component, it just a conditial which says that it necesary to render Home component but as Menu is a view that can be see in all component's view (because is in IonSplitPane ) I need to render it too when home is call.

Comment: is the menu component meant to be the <menu/> that is always rendered on top, whilst the only thing that changes are if "init" or "home are visible ? so <menu/>?

Comment: <Menu /> must change what it shows when /home is called from init, this is why I want to render menu, when the <Redirect push = {true} to = "/ home" /> statement is performed